# eigenvalues and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Say that A is a nxn matrice with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let vector $\vec{v}$
∈ Ker((B − λIn)$^2$) but not an element of  Ker(B − λIn). (I have proved the contrary to be true though). How do i show that {$\vec{v}$ ,(B − λIn)$\vec{v}$} are linearly independent. I tried using

$c_1$$\vec{v}$ + $c_2$(B − λIn)$\vec{v}$ = 0 and expanding it in all sorts of ways but i can't show that $c_1$ and $c_2$ is 0. How do i show these two are linearly independent i must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c_1v+c_2(B-\lambda I)v=0$ then applying $B-\lambda I$ to both sides gives $$c_1(B-\lambda I)v+c_2(B-\lambda I)^2v=0$$ Since $v\in \text{ker}\Big[(B- \lambda I)^2\Big]$ we must have $c_1(B-\lambda I)v=0$. Now since $v\notin \text{ker}\Big[(B- \lambda I)\Big]$ we know $(B- \lambda I)v \neq 0$ telling us $c_1=0$ so original equation becomes $c_2(B-\lambda I)v=0$. Again, using the fact that $v\notin \text{ker}\Big[(B- \lambda I)\Big]$ we get $c_2=0$ as well.